# What is a Sharp Number™?

Tags: pattern

*This puzzle is based off and inspired by the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) and [What is a Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20phrase%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) and their spin-off [What is a Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) series.*

This was originally going to be a challenge for [Code Golf SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com), but first I wanted to see whether someone can figure it out without me telling so.

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it a Sharp Number™. Find whether a number is "sharp".

| Sharp Numbers™ | Non-Sharp Numbers™ |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 37 | 20 |
| 62 | 22 |
| 81 | 42 |
| 439 | 863 |
| 482 | 5364 |
| 2745 | 123456789 |

Note that each of the numbers can be tested individually; there is no pattern among different Sharp Numbers™

Hint:

> why is the flat log of the parts

Hint 2:

> don't fall down the axis!

Comment: Is it possible that you can put this in ascending or descending order, or does this jumble of numbers part of the puzzle?

Comment: @VarunW. No, as I said there is no relation among the different Sharp Numbers™

Comment: So this puzzle is not like an input and output puzzle?

Comment: This puzzle is whether a number fits a certain rule

Comment: Just to see if im on the right track... Is f ex 362 and 730 both examples of "Sharp numbers"?

Comment: @Prim3numbah correct. they are sharp (ignore my deleted comment)

Comment: I see a pattern here, but can't make sense of why it's called "sharp".. I'll have to think some more